# Maven build with AnnotationProcessor that parses files in src/main/java and generates sources to generated-test-sources/test-annotations

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, annotations, code-generation

I'm using maven 3.0.3 and Java7.

I've got an AnnotationProcessor that is supposed to parse annotated java-files in `src/main/java` (**not** `src/test/java`) and generate Helper-Classes for JUnit-Tests. These Helper-Classes are supposed to be stored in `target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations` because they use libraries that are only available in test-scope. (Note: everything works fine as long as this dependency isn't in test-scope, but the build fails as soon as it is. It's definitely only needed in test-scope / during unit-tests and compilation of test-classes.)

I tried several configurations without any luck:

1. I configured the `maven-compiler-plugin` to use the AnnotationProcessor during `compile:compile`. The generated HelperClass would be stored in `generated-sources/annotations`. **Not** in `generated-test-sources/test-annotations` as desired. The result was, that Test-Scoped dependencies would not have been used. Build failed due to Compilation Error "cannot find symbol". *Fail*
2. I used the above configuration and redefined the generatedSourcesDirectory:

   ```
   <generatedSourcesDirectory>
      ${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
   </generatedSourcesDirectory>
   ```

   The generated class would be stored in `generated-test-sources/test-annotations` as expected, but the build still failed because it tried to compile that file as above and missed the test-scoped dependencies. *Fail*
3. I tried to use the above configuration and excluded `**/generated-test-sources/test-annotations/**/*.java` in order to prevent the compiler from compiling in this phase:

   ```
   <excludes>
      <exclude>**/generated-test-sources/test-annotations/**/*.java</exclude>
   </excludes>
   ```

   no luck. Same Compiler-Error as above. *Fail*
4. I configured the `maven-compiler-plugin` to use the AnnotationProcessor during `test-compile:testCompile`. The HelperClass might theoretically have been generated in `generated-test-sources/test-annotations`, but the AnnotationProcessor wouldn't stumble upon the annotated class that is located in `src/main/java`, not in `src/test/java`, which is AFAIK the compilation-scope during `test-compile:testCompile`. So the Annotated class would not be found, the HelperClass would not be generated and could therefore not be stored in `generated-test-sources`. *Fail*
5. Tried to run that during `compile:testCompile` and `test-compile:compile`, which lead in both cases to classes of src/main/java not yet being compiled - thus compiler error. *Fail*

What I really would like to do is:

1. Configure the compiler to use the AnnotationProcessor during `compile:compile` to generate my HelperClass to `${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations` **but don't let maven compile it**
2. Then compile the HelperClass during `test-compile:testCompile`.

I'm failing to do so. I'm not sure if I am missing important maven basics (concept) here, or if there's a problem with the exclusion configuration, or whatever it is.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I performed several tests with `includes`, `excludes`, `testExcludes` and so on (which I find rather badly documented). It seems that maven simply ignores these configuration settings. Can't really believe it, but though it showed that includes and excludes have been configured correctly and these configurations where used (mvn -X clean install), it still compiled excluded files or didn't compile included files. (BTW: I tested it from CLI as well, as I found out that some IDEs still ignore those settings.)
Any solutions found out there, like adding resource directories, including, excluding, defining `generatedTestSourcesDirectory` during `test-compile:testCompile` to match the `generatedSourcesDirectory` of `compile:compile` simply didn't work. 
Whatever.

**I found a way to solve the problem as follows:**

1. let the first compile-step (`compile:compile`) only use Annotation-Processors, but don't compile generated classes: `<proc>only</proc>`. Define the `generatedSourcesDirectory` to be where test-sources should be generated to: `${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations`.
2. use `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add test-source-directory in the correct phase and goal.
   The implicit `test-compile:testCompile` would then be executed with the generated classes sourcepath added to the normal sourcepath.

Below is my configuration. Note that I need to generate other stuff before my actual problem occurs and that has to be generated into `generated-sources/annotations`, so there's one compile-step more than needed for the solution.

So, this is it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- normal compile and generation of other classes to standard location (implicit, you shouldn't need that) -->
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Generates Test-Helper-Class into ${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations WITHOUT compiling it -->
                    <id>compile-TestHelperClass</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessors>
                            <annotationProcessor>org.my.UnitTestGenerationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        </annotationProcessors>
                        <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                        <!-- generated class depends on test-scope libs, so don't compile now: proc:only DISABLES compilation of generated classes-->
                        <proc>only</proc>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- implicit test-compile:testCompile -->
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- adds source-dir during generate-test-sources:add-test-source 
                 so that the path to our generated class is now known to the 
                 compiler during test-compile:testCompile -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: the id `compile-TestHelperClass` should be renamed to `generate-TestHelperClass` since the comment says `WITHOUT compiling`

Comment: I would only add that the `compile-TestHelperClass` execution of maven-compiler-plugin should be bound to `generate-test-sources` phase to have it in a proper place.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, and tried the suggested solution (two executions of maven-compiler-plugin, the first time with `proc:none` and the second time with `proc:only`) but ran into the following issues:

1) Running `mvn clean install` : both executions (`proc:none` and `proc:only`) will compile the source code and generate class files, before running the annotation processor:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ foo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to <mumble>\foo\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (process-annotations) @ foo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to <mumble>\foo\target\classes
[MyAnnotationProcessor] processing ...
```

2) Running `mvn install` after a previous install: both executions (`proc:none` and `proc:only`) determine that the class files are up to date and do nothing, and the annotation processor is not run:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ foo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (process-annotations) @ foo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

So in the first case, the java files are compiled twice (and one of my modules has thousands of files, and this affects build time significantly). And in the second case, nothing happens at all because the class files already exist. This is using version 3.1 and 3.0 of `maven-compiler-plugin`.

For `maven-compiler-plugin` version 2.5.1, the second execution (`proc:only`) would always determine that class files were up to date and not run the annotation processor, whether I was running `mvn clean install` or `mvn install`, so the second execution was pointless.

The plugin is configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <configuration>
        <proc>none</proc>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>process-annotations</id>
      <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <proc>only</proc>
        <annotationProcessors>
          <annotationProcessor>MyAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </plugin>
```

So `proc:only` option seems to compile the source code anyway in version 3.0 and 3.1 (making it the same as `proc:both`, which affects performance) or take no action in version 2.5.1 (making it the same as `proc:none`, which affects functionality).

Not sure how to get around this problem ...

**Edit #1**

The verbose output includes the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (process-annotations) @ foo ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) annotationProcessors = [MyAnnotationProcessor]
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = <mumble>\foo
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = <mumble>\foo\target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [<mumble>\foo\target\classes, ...]
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [<mumble>\foo\src\main\java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = <mumble>\foo\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile {execution: process-annotations}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = <mumble>\foo\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) proc = only
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = foo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = true
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@6fb65730
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@6fb65730
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [<mumble>\foo\src\main\java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [<mumble>\foo\target\classes ... ]
[DEBUG] Output directory: <mumble>\foo\target\classes
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  <mumble>\foo\target\classes ...
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  <mumble>\foo\src\main\java
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d <mumble>\foo\target\classes
    -classpath <mumble>\foo\target\classes;...;
    -sourcepath <mumble>\foo\src\main\java;
    -s <mumble>\foo\target\generated-sources\annotations
    -proc:only
    -processor MyAnnotationProcessor
    -g -verbose -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to <mumble>\foo\target\classes
[parsing started RegularFileObject[<mumble>\foo\src\main\java\Foo.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
...
[search path for source files: <mumble>\foo\src\main\java]
[MyAnnotationProcessor] processing ...
```

Even though there's a `proc:only` in the compiler options there's still a `[parsing started RegularFileObject]` entry ... maybe it's just logging that but actually loads the class file?

Answer (score 1):

To be perfectly honest, maven-compiler-plugin generally sucks.  I use a third party plugin that seems to always work correctly for me.  I just use `<proc>none</proc>` for maven-compiler-plugin, then:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>annogen</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
              <processors>
                <processor>
                  xapi.dev.processor.AnnotationMirrorProcessor
                </processor>
              </processors>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
              <appendSourceArtifacts>true</appendSourceArtifacts>
              <additionalSourceDirectories>
                <additionalSourceDirectory>
                  ${project.basedir}/../api/src/main/java
                </additionalSourceDirectory>
              </additionalSourceDirectories>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this blog post:
http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/

It looks like you need to set the following in pom.xml

build>plugins>plugin>configuration>compilerArgument>-proc:none

I'm not sure if this applies to your particular situation, but I was working with annotations yesterday, and thought this may help you.

It looks like this argument will let you compile without any annotation processors. Then you can compile with them at a later point in the life cycle.

Comment: My AnnotationProcessors do generally work. My problem is: during `compile:compile`, the test-scoped dependencies needed for the generated class are not visible to the compiler (that tries to compile the generated class) and during `test-compile:testCompile` the AnnotationProcessor won't be invoked for the annotated class that is located in src/main/java (not in src/main/test)