# Dagger 2: Separate Module for testing declared in src/test/java

Tags: maven, dagger-2

I have a Maven project and defined a module + component in `src/main/java`, which Dagger 2 is handling as expected.

Now I want to mock some dependencies for my unit tests. However the dagger-compiler seems to ignore components inside `src/test/java`.

Is there a way of telling Dagger 2 to also look inside my test source set?

(Not an Android project)

Answer (score 1):

Ok found my mistake. For others having the same problem: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853585/maven-build-with-annotationprocessor-that-parses-files-in-src-main-java-and-gene) gave me the correct hint.

Components declared in `src/test/java` are generated to `target/generated-test-sources/`. This is an annotation processing default, not Dagger's fault. I just didn't have the idea to look for directories other than `target/generated-sources`...